# How to add a main view controller to a tab bar controller that is not one of the tab bar items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, tabbarcontroller

i'm building a to do list app that have a main page that I want to use for presenting some data in, and this main page have 3 action buttons that are:

List button - takes you to a page which present a list of things

Create button - takes you to the page where you create a new item

Profile button - takes you to the profile page

I want those action to be presented as tab bar buttons, but when I created a tabbarviewcontroller in the storyboard I notice that the main page is the first tab bar item...and it's not what i want to be the initial screen...

Can anyone please help me to figure it out?

I want the main screen to be some king of view controller that have 3 tab bar buttons, but each one of them is different than the initial screen.

this is what i want:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: it is not possible with tab bar in normal scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not common navigation but if you want you can create a UIView with buttons and put in bottom of ViewController mother (Home page) and handle navigation with event segues simulating a UITabBarController

Comment: but isn't a tabbar giving me a good functionality that i can use? or i can acomplish all the functionality with just using buttons on a view controller..? @German

Comment: You have to work more on the constrains to look better on different devices, but you can accomplish all the functions of UITabBarController, until now I've done well.

Answer (score 0):

In such kind of apps, the home page should be a tabbarcontroller.  You can check a tabor example for this with storyboards.

Comment: check out the photo i added, this is what i need :) thanks@! @user1376138

Comment: You can do this by adding buttons on view and put that view on your window and bring that view to top. You need to handle navigation manually and it will work like charm.